# Help me understand how Search function works using dynamic_sidebar()

Tags: php, search

On my existing website, there is a search box at the top of the page.

My understanding is that it's from this code in header.php

```
<div id="search_sec">
   <?php dynamic_sidebar('search');?>
</div>
```

which, as I understand, calls a sidebar that is registered in functions.php

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'id' => 'search',
    'name'=>'Search',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => ''
    )
);
```

But these lines are only for displaying stuff and does not contain anything that actually calls a search function, presumably at searchform.php

Can you please help me understand the connection from header.php to searchform.php?

Furthermore, if I rename the sidebar ID from "search" to "search1" and call dynamic_sidebar("search1"), nothing is displayed. Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: this does most likely depend on some additional coding in your theme - please add more information to your question.

Comment: Hi Michael. What more info is needed? At this point I'm clueless as too what is relevant to the topic at hand. Basically I'm just trying to do a trace from the search input field to the search result. And I'm stumped at the dynamic_sidebar() because it does not look like it's calling any search function (just displaying the box and that's it).

Comment: The search form has an `input` named `s`. When the form is submitted, just like any standard HTML form, it directs you to example.com/?s=search+term. WordPress itself queries posts based on this parameter.

Comment: it might help to know exactly what theme you  are using, and possibly what the theme's developer has to say to the question...

Comment: Jacob: I understand this part (which happens in searchform.php), but not the part immediately precedes it. Namely, how does the form gets submitted and searchform.php gets called (from dynamic_sidebar()).